# Топология меша в Blender

Tags: 3d, blender, mesh

Делаю модель охотничьей винтовки с прицелом.

Создавая меш к примеру ствола, я делаю его единым то есть все детали ствола перетекают в другие вне зависимости от их сложности естественно это занимает больше времени, тем не менее на ютубе огромное количество видео где моделят целый кусок (в реальном мире) все по частям и просто "топят" одни объекты в других создавая иллюзию целостности объекта, так как какой подход правильный?

И ещё попутно вопрос про трисы, при моделировании единым мешем у меня появляются моменты где все таки приходится использовать треугольники, к примеру в модели винтовки у меня 5 трисов все остальные 4 угольники, это допустимо или нужно все выводит на 4 угольники?

Answer (score 2):

*Вопрос достаточно общий, вы даже не указываете целевое использование для вашей модели (мобилка, ААА игра, фотореализм, кинематограф, 3д печать). Вот вам общий ответ:*

1. Оба подхода "правильные". Многие объекты естественно состоят из частей - их и делают частями.

   - Цельный меш обычно более избыточен, но с более "красивыми" стыками частей.
   - "Лоскутный" меш быстрее делать, он легко делится на части, например для текстурирования.
2. Это неизбежно. Смотрите на артефакты при рендере, если их не видно, то смысла "исправлять" нету.

Не гонитесь за перфекционизмом. Делайте то что надо, так чтобы это выглядело хорошо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, модель делаю для фотореализма. Просто думаю уже профессионально работать в этой сфере, по этому хотел знать какой подход реально показывает уровень профессионализма